# how to use the puppetdb API to combine facts

Tags: curl, puppet

I'm using puppet version 5.3.6.

I'm able to query the puppetdb and get lots of useful information like this:

```
$ curl -s -X GET http://localhost:8080/pdb/query/v4/facts --data-urlencode 'query=["extract", [["function","count"],"value"],["=","name","operatingsystem"],["group_by", "value"]]' | python -mjson.tool
[
    {
        "count": 339,
        "value": "OracleLinux"
    },
    {
        "count": 73,
        "value": "RedHat"
    }
]
```

AND:

```
$ curl -s -X GET http://localhost:8080/pdb/query/v4/facts --data-urlencode 'query=["extract", [["function","count"],"value"],["=","name","operatingsystemmajrelease"],["group_by", "value"]]' | python -mjson.tool
[
    {
        "count": 38,
        "value": "5"
    },
    {
        "count": 217,
        "value": "6"
    },
    {
        "count": 157,
        "value": "7"
    }
]
```

How can I combine the two together and get each Oracle/Red Hat release & major release grouped together in an easy to see view. I've tried a few different ways to do it but I'm not able to find any examples or docs that can explain to me how to do it.

Other useful combinations would be all Red Hat servers in a particular DC running operatingsystemmajrelease 6 (or show all of them?). This would involve combining three facts.

This would be very useful.

Comment: Your best bet here is to write a wrapper script around your queries that combines and formats the responses. I would recommend the Python bindings to greatly facilitate that: https://github.com/voxpupuli/pypuppetdb. I do not have enough experience around the Python bindings for the PuppetDB REST API to give an answer, but this will definitely help you out. Specifically check out the `facts` and `query builder` sections of the documentation.

Comment: I was hoping i could combine my query with an "and" or an "or" to help build up the matches and results. I will check out the ling thanks Matt.       If someone doesn know if this is possible I'd be happy to hear. Thanks

Comment: Well you can definitely do that that kind of query enhancement with the Python bindings. If your hope was to do it with curl, then I think you would get stuck writing complicated shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I had similar problem. I solved it with:

```
curl -s -X GET http://localhost:8080/pdb/query/v4/inventory -d 'query=["extract", [["function", "count"],"facts.operatingsystem","facts.operatingsystemrelease"],["group_by","facts.operatingsystem","facts.operatingsystemrelease"]]'
```